# How could I use .bak file?

Tags: editors, sourcecode

I used WinEdt 10 for making tex, but today I found the tex file empty. I found a bak file on my desktop, but I don't know how could I use that. I tried changing .bak to .tex, but it didn't work.

[image: here is the picture of bak file.]

Comment: You could try opening the `.bak` file with a different editor, for example Notepad, and see what is inside.

Comment: There are such codes, as you can see in the picture.

Comment: That seems like meta-data, and not your original LaTeX code. Maybe further down in the file there is something more useful? If the whole file is like this then it is not a backup.

Comment: Yes, the whole file is like this. Thank you

Comment: you found a backup of some other file from winedt.  On my system the file backups are in a folder _history beside the winedt team folder in appdata.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer, thank you so much. I found my lost file there.

Comment: btw: you can also access the backup files by right clicking on the document tab in winedt. There is a "open backup" entry. And you can change the backup options in winedt options, backup.ini also contains some explanations how winedt backups work.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer, I really appreciate your help.